# Realizar operaciones matematicas en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hasta el momento solo he trabajado con tratamiento de informacion en Rails, empresas, articulos, productos, etc. Sin embargo hay algo que nunca he realizado y curiosamente no encuentro informacion explicita al respecto, sino mas bien, directamente en Ruby mas no en Rails, claramente las operaciones deben ser iguales, pero la colocacion y tratamiento posiblemente diferente, yendo al punto, un ejemplo facil seria la   calcular de forma dinamica las notas promedios de un estudiante, tomando en consideracion que las primeras 3 notas cada una valen el 20%, y el examen final un 40%, lo planteare mas explicitamente a continuacion:

```
Periodo1 //Tabla
----------------------------------------------
f.note_1 //field (20%)
f.note_2 //field (20%)
f.note_3 //field (20%)
f.final_examn //field (40%)
Promedio //Total
```

Esto se me ocurre que se podria realizar directamente desde la vista:

```
<% @average %> = (<%= f.note_1 %>*(20%)) + (<%= f.note_2 %>*(20%)) + (<%= f.note_3 %>*(20%) + (<%= f.final_examn %>*(40%)

<%= @average %>
```

Aunque posiblemente esto no sea lo mas correcto en el sentido que la logica no es tan recomendable realizarla desde la vista, agradecere mucho puedan orientarme y darme un ejemplo de como funciona esta parte de Rails, Saludos!

Comment: ¿De dónde obtienes `note_1`, `note_2`, `note_3`, `final_exam` y de dónde los porcentajes?

Comment: Gerry, son los campos, a un lado especifico (field), esos campos pueden pertenecer a X modelo, los porcentajes son una suposicion de lo que podrian valer cada campo, imaginate q tengas 7 en un examen, ese examen lo multiplicas o lo divides por el porcentaje que vale esa nota, ¿me copias? Nos estamos situando en un formulario de X recurso

Comment: Ok, entiendo la lógica, sin embargo es importante saber donde vendrían los porcentajes, eso determinará el mejor lugar para poner el código (en un helper, en el controlador, en un modelo, o en algún otro lado). ¿También serían campos del modelo?

Comment: No, los porcentajes ya serian algo fijo, no tendrian que cambiar, aunque no esta mal la idea, de que puedan estar dentro de un campo, en caso de que sean dinamicos, de que forma afectaria una o la otra al momento de manejarlos? No seria practicamente igual, ya que en este caso sustituyo el valor fijo por el llamado al parametro que tiene el porcentaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que los campos provienen del modelo, lo mejor sería tener un método en el modelo que te entregue el promedio en lugar de calcularlo en la vista.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que tu modelo se llame `Student` con los atributos `note_1`, `note_2`, `note_3`, `final_exam`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

**Modelo**

```
class Student < ApplicationController
  PCT = { note_1: 0.2, note_2: 0.2, note_3: 0.2, final_exam: 0.4 }
  # asociaciones, validaciones, etc.

  def average()
    PCT.map { |note, pct| self[note] * pct }.reduce(:+) 
  end
end
```

- `PCT` mantendrá los valores fijos de los porcentajes (estos idealmente podrían ir en un modelo en caso que puedan cambiar más adelante para evitar la necesidad de modificar el código).

**Controlador**

```
@student = Student.find(1)
```

**Vista**

```
<%= @student.average %>
```

Comment: ¿Ese metodo saca el promedio? ¿Que es lo que hace que lo divida? .reduce? ya que tiene como valor +

Comment: En el método repliqué tu fórmula únicamente, es decir, es equivalente a `(note_1 * 0.2) + (note_2 * 0.2) + (note_3 * 0.2) + (final_exam * 0.4)`.

Comment: Imaginate el caso de una universidad, que usualmente un ciclo tiene 3 periodos, y cada periodo tiene la misma logica, nota1, nota2, nota3, parcial, y ese procedimiento se tiene que realizar 3 veces en un mismo ciclo, por lo que al final se suman los promedios de cada periodo para sacar el total del ciclo, tendria que realizar un metodo por periodo, o basta siempre con uno solo? posiblemente se podrian agregar 2 PCT mas

Comment: @HectorHernandez Depende como definas tu modelo; por ejemplo: un estudiante tendría 4 notas por cada parcial, por lo que podrías tener 12 columnas en total en tu modelo. O bien, podrías generar un modelo `Parcial` en el cual guardes las notas. La fórmula como tal podría variar; sin embargo la lógica de _dónde_ va el código es la misma: **en el modelo** (ya sea en `Student`o en `Parcial`). ¿Me explico?

Comment: Claro Gerry! Perfectamente! Agradezco muchisimo tu tiempo y amabilidad, me queda claro, en conclusion, si los datos se tienen que almacenar en la BD lo recomendable es hacerlo en el modelo, una ultima duda, para ti, el promedio se almacena? o solo simplemente las notas y parciales?

Comment: @HectorHernandez Así es, si está en la BD la mayoría de las veces la lógica va en el modelo (como siempre, hay excepciones). Dado que el promedio podrá cambiar con cada nota yo lo dejaría como fórmula, es decir, únicamente almacenaría las notas y parciales.

Comment: Si lo mismo pensaba ya que estas notas podrian modificarse, y no tendria mucho sentido tener un promedio ya almcenado, previamente! Gracias por el dato Gerry! =D

Answer (score 0):

1) Rails es 100% ruby. Puedes usar todas las opciones de este lenguaje + lo que agrega este framework. En este caso todo lo que leas sobre Ruby lo puedes usar en Rails.

2) El método que estas usando ES CASI CORRECTO. La lógica es la correcta pero lo estás haciendo mal en dos partes: Primero en vez de usar 20% usa el flotante 0.2. Segundo todo debería ir dentro de los marcadores de ruby embebido de tu vista <% %>. Ahora estás dejando los operadores matemáticos fuera y por lo tanto tu formula no hace nada. Debería ser así (asumiendo que la variable local "f" que usas en tu ejemplo existe):

```
<%= @final_score = f.note_1 * 0.2 + f.note_2 * 0.2 + f.note_3 * 0.2 + f.final_examn * 0.4 %>
```

3) La buena práctica sería que hagas esta operación en el modelo u otro objeto, pero no en la vista que no debería ocuparse de esto.

```
#Model
class ObjetoDondeEstanLasNotas < ApplicationController
  def final_score
    self.note_1 * 0.2 + self.note_2 * 0.2 + self.note_3 * 0.2 +  self.note_4 * 0.4
  end
end
```